# Use the same jquery object in a call

Tags: jquery

Not sure quite how to describe this but this is what i want to achieve:

```
$('.class').append($(this).attr("unit"));
```

but this doesn't append anything, i don't believe that $(this) is the element.

Im not sure how to do this, but if there is a better way like attaching code to an event on a div, but i can't think of any triggers that work on load.

Comment: Are you trying to copy a child element to the end of the parent element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) here to loop though and have `this` be what you want, like this:

```
$('.class').each(function() {
  $(this).append($(this).attr("unit"));
});
```

Inside the `.each()` callback closure, `this` refers to the current `class="class"` element you're on, and runs for each match.